# Changing the src path of html5 audio element using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am creating a control that contains an html5 audio element and I want to be able to change the source of the audio dynamically. I can access the audio element in C# but am unable to figure out how to change the src attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this way?

```
audioElement.Attributes["src"] = "something";
```